# javafx spinner value listener causing infinite loop

Tags: java, javafx, spinner

I have an application with SimpleDoubleProperties bidirectionally bound to Spinners, which all interact, ie as one changes this will need to perform calculations to change the rest.

Due to this setting the value on one spinner then causes them to all to change, and then calls their change calc listener.  This goes back and forth, as each one keeps setting the other in an infinate loop.

Is there a way to update valueA or B or C here, which sets the other two values without them recalcing the others again?

Thanks

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SpinnerBindDemo extends Application {
    SimpleDoubleProperty valueA = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100.0);
    SimpleDoubleProperty valueB = new SimpleDoubleProperty(55.5);
    SimpleDoubleProperty valueC = new SimpleDoubleProperty(41.0);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Spinner spinnerA = new Spinner();
        spinnerA.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0.0, 999.9, valueA.get(), 0.1));
        spinnerA.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(valueA);
        valueA.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            valuesChanged("A", (double) newValue);
        });

        Spinner spinnerB = new Spinner();
        spinnerB.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0.0, 999.9, valueB.get(), 0.1));
        spinnerB.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(valueB);
        valueB.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            valuesChanged("B", (double) newValue);
        });

        Spinner spinnerC = new Spinner();
        spinnerC.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0.0, 999.9, valueC.get(), 0.1));
        spinnerC.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(valueC);
        valueC.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            valuesChanged("C", (double) newValue);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(spinnerA);
        root.getChildren().add(spinnerB);
        root.getChildren().add(spinnerC);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
        stage.setTitle("Demo");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    private void valuesChanged(String changedValue, double value){
        System.out.println("Value "+changedValue+" changed, calc "+value);
        if(changedValue.equals("A")){
            //some calc
            valueB.set(value - 33.3);
            valueC.set(value - 22.1);
        }else if(changedValue.equals("B")){
            //some calc
            valueA.set(value + 11);
            valueC.set(value + 12);

        }else if(changedValue.equals("C")){
            //some calc
            valueB.set(value - +15);
            valueA.set(value - 2.2);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Year 2020 still  spinner is looping at random occasion huh :) welcome to javaFX :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear (to me, anyway) the logic you're trying to enforce here, but you can consider setting a flag to indicate a change is in process:

```
public class SpinnerBindDemo extends Application {

    private boolean changing = false ;

    // ...

    private void valuesChanged(String changedValue, double value){

        if (changing) {
            return ;
        }

        changing = true ;

        System.out.println("Value "+changedValue+" changed, calc "+value);
        if(changedValue.equals("A")){
            //some calc
            valueB.set(value - 33.3);
            valueC.set(value - 22.1);
        }else if(changedValue.equals("B")){
            //some calc
            valueA.set(value + 11);
            valueC.set(value + 12);

        }else if(changedValue.equals("C")){
            //some calc
            valueB.set(value - +15);
            valueA.set(value - 2.2);
        }

        changing = false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I've not made it very clear.  
The values I'm setting do not matter here, were just to demonstrate it keeps calling the other value listeners.
Ideally if A changes, it would update B&Cs values, but not trigger updates from them
However you should be able to chnage B with the spinner, which would update A&C

Comment: Yes.
Orginally my issue was more complicated due to other method calls not included in the demo, but I've simplied it down to be surrounded by the check
Thanks